# Sum two textbox values and get grade letter in third textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an HTML form with three textboxes. I want to sum them automatically using jQuery. At the same time, I want to use `if`–`else` statements to check if the result in third textbox is greater than `100`. The value in the next (forth textbox)should be `A`.

See the code below :

```
<form>

    <input type="text" class="number">
    <input type="text" class="number">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="total" disabled />
    <input type="text" id="total2" disable />


   <!--i want the letter A to appear in forth textbox if the value in third textbox is > 100 ---->

</form>

<script>
$('.number').keyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.number').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('#total').val(sum);

    if ($('#total').val(sum) > 100) {
        form.total2.value = "A";
    }   
 });
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Java != Javascript.

Comment: What is your question? Is something not working? Where’s the rest of your script? Why is there a stray `} });`? Where’s your HTML? Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: `if (sum > 1) {` probably is what you wish to do...

Comment: yeah but not working

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.number').on('keyup',function(){

  var sum = 0;
  var grade = 'B';

  $('.number').each(function(){
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });

  $('#sum').text(sum);

  if(sum>100){
    grade = 'A';
  }
  $('#grade').text(grade);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="textbox" class="number" placeholder="number 1">
<input type="textbox" class="number" placeholder="number 2">
<div>
  Your total mark is <span id="sum">0</span>.
  <br>
  Your grade is <span id="grade">F</span>.
</div>
```

Comment: ok brother thanks  it works but i want the result to appear in textbox with id #total2

Comment: @ClicHere That would of course be done exactly the same way as the above; just use an input field with your desired ID in place of the span with `#grade` used here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
$('.number').keyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.number').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#total').val(sum);

    if (sum > 100) {
       $('#total2').val("A");}   
 });
```